# Local wordpress install only shows home page, all other pages Not Found

Tags: htaccess, localhost

I am working on a local install of a live wordpress site, all links from the main page show Not Found errors. all .htaccess files are all present.

The problem is that every page except for the home page is showing a Not Found error, I can't find any problems with permissions or anything else that would cause it to not work.

Is there anything that I can try that I might be overlooking? I apologize for the vauge questions but I am having trouble figuring out where to start.

Comment: Live site is installed in domain root? What is the address of local site? How did you migrate it? Have you recreated htaccess files (with correct contents)? Have you updated posts permalinks?

Comment: Sounds like permalinks need refreshed. Settings -> Permalinks. Try again.

Comment: the address is localhost:8888/sites/GaugeSite (I am using MAMP)

I migrated it with SSH and a tarball, I made sure the .htaccess files are good to go, and I updated the permalinks as GhostToast suggests, problems still persist

Comment: Are you allowed by your Apache configuration to use `.htaccess`?  Check your config files for an `AllowOverride` directive.  If you see `AllowOverride None`, you'll need to change this (most of my sites use `AllowOverride All`) and restart your Apache service/daemon.

Answer (score 2):

With localhost, you need to make sure that your mod_rewrite is on. You can do this in your httpd.conf file in MAMP. MAMP > CONF > APACHE > ORIGINAL > httpd.conf. Uncomment this line:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: … and restart the server then.